# Function decode_short_URL from twitteR package not working

Tags: r, twitter-oauth, sentiment-analysis, tweets, url-shortener

I am using `decode_short_url` of the `twitteR` package to  decode shortened URLs from Twitter posts, but I am not able to get the desired results, It is always giving back the same results such as:

```
decode_short_url(decode_short_url("http://bit.ly/23226se656"))

## http://bit.ly/23226se656
## [1] "http://bit.ly/23226se656
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE** I wrapped this functionality in a [package](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/longurl) and managed to get it [on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/longurl/index.html) same-day. Now, you can just do:

```
library(longurl)

expand_urls("http://bit.ly/23226se656", check=TRUE, warn=TRUE)
|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100%

## Source: local data frame [1 x 2]
## 
##                   orig_url expanded_url
## 1 http://bit.ly/23226se656           NA
## 
## Warning message:
## In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : client error: (404) Not Found
```

You can pass in a vector of URLs and get a `data_frame`/`data.frame` back in that form.

---

That particular bit.ly URL gives a `404` error. Here's a version of `decode_short_url` that has an optional `check` parameter that will attempt a `HEAD` request and throw a warning message for any HTTP status other than 200.

You can further modify it to return `NA` in the event the "expanded" link 404's (I have no idea what you need this to really do in the event the link is bad).

NOTE that the addd `HEAD` request will significantly slow the process down, so you may want to do a first pass with `check=FALSE` to a separate column, then compare which weren't "expanded", then check those with `check=TRUE`.

You might also want to rename this to avoid namespace conflicts with the one from `twitteR`.

```
decode_short_url <- function(url, check=FALSE, ...) {

  require(httr)

  request_url <- paste("http://api.longurl.org/v2/expand?url=", 
                      url, "&format=json", sep="")
  response <- GET(request_url, query=list(useragent="twitteR"), ...)

  parsed <- content(response, as="parsed")

  ret <- NULL
  if (!("long-url" %in% names(parsed))) {
    ret <- url
  } else {
    ret <- parsed[["long-url"]]
  }

  if (check) warn_for_status(HEAD(url))

  return(url)

}

decode_short_url("http://bit.ly/23226se656", check=TRUE)

## [1] "http://bit.ly/23226se656"
## Warning message:
## In decode_short_url("http://bit.ly/23226se656", check = TRUE) :
##   client error: (404) Not Found
```

Comment: Thanks for the help there, but it is still not working for me on few other short URL I had, Python's "urlib2" module and a function defined for a class is working fine for me. But Yes while trying this on python I am still missing R